# SQLite odd behavior with NOT LIKE

Tags: sqlite

Using the Skype SQLite database, and DB Browser for SQLite (v3.7.0)

This returns 13 records:

```
select * from messages where chatname not like '%pdx.%';
```

This returns a count of 0:

```
select count(*) from messages where chatname not like '%pdx.%';
```

This doesn't delete anything:

```
delete from messages where chatname not like '%pdx.%';
```

Does anyone know why SQLite might do this? Given that the first two queries have the same condition on the same table, the count(*) of records should be equal to the number of rows selected in the first query right? And why does the DELETE not affect any rows when it uses the same condition as the first query which does return records?

I've tried with several different SQLite front-end tools, and all seem to do the same.

Comment: Shows the contents of some rows that you think are wrongly handled.

Comment: @CL. Well if the first select query returns 13 records (and it does), then the second query (COUNT) with the exact same WHERE condition against the same table should return a count of 13. But instead it returns a count of 0.

Comment: Show some [example data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5).

Comment: @CL I'm unclear why you feel this is needed. But OK. The select * query returns a record whose chatname is "adrian.l.parker", but the count(*) query with the identical WHERE condition returns a count of 0.

Comment: I want to see the original data, not the result. Create an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5).

Comment: It's perfectly valid SQL, it would work on any MySQL, PostGres or MSSQL database. If validating the SQL is in question, I can tell you it's valid.

Comment: I want to validate the matching of the *data*.

Comment: Here is a different way of providing what @CL is asking for:
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
For SQLIte, an MCVE includes a `.dump` of your SQLITE database.  
That database is of course one without any classified data. The smallest database in which you, but more importantly we, can reproduce what you describe. This provides a little redundancy, which helps when misunderstandings seem present. It also is simple convenience, answerers don't like to invent and populate test databases.